# Uso de floor en un trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Buen dia disculpen tengo este trigger para insertar un getdate en el resgistro cuyo codigoM sea FLOOR (m.codigoM) pero no me realiza la operación estoy pensando que lo a mejor es muy ambiguo las condiciones que le estoy poniendo.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER fechaactual
    ON casos
    FOR INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN


    UPDATE m
    SET m.fecha = GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i INNER JOIN datos m ON i.codigoM = FLOOR (m.codigoM)
    WHERE t.fecha = NULL
END
```

Comment: Raúl, sobre que tabla es el Trigger?, que significa que no realiza la operación? no actualiza ningún dato? te da un error?

Comment: Ya puse el trigger completo, no actualiza ningun dato

Comment: No tiene nada que ver pero hay un alias que no esta definido `t` imagino que es `m`. Yo revisaría que existan casos a modificar mediante `select * from datos m inner join casos c on c.codigoM = FLOOR (m.codigoM) WHERE m.fecha = NULL AND c.codigoM = <codigoM a probar>`

Comment: Probe tu codigo y no me muestra ningun registro pero si tengo un codigoM 2 y 2.1

Comment: A ver si te lo puedo poner un poco más claro, tal como está la consulta si insertas `casos.codigoM = 2` debieran actualizarse `datos.codigoM in (2, 2.1)`, pero si insertas `casos.codigoM = 2.1` no se va a actualizar nada por que estás comparando `i.codigoM = FLOOR (m.codigoM)` es decir `2.1 = 2`